# Using Google Script, how can I insert an image into a table cell?

Tags: javascript, image, google-apps-script

I have been successful in figuring out how to append an image using the answer below but I need to take it one step further.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970134/1208721

Using Google Script in Apps, how do you specifically reference a cell in a table on a google doc and append the image there? I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

Thanks!
Nate

Comment: It might help to post a small snippet of the code you've tried so far that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the cell formula to this one:

```
=Image("http://www.cardinalpath.com/cpwp/wp-content/themes/cardinalpath/images/cp_logo.png")
```

If you want this image to link somewhere you can even do this:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.cardinalpath.com/",Image("http://www.cardinalpath.com/cpwp/wp-content/themes/cardinalpath/images/cp_logo.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Continue using =image as described by Eduardo, but instead of range.setValue() use [range.setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#setFormula)  Just realize you can't use this from the cell itself, like in =mycustomfunction(args) as in that case, you can only modify the cell contents of the current cell.